# Unable to access mule-worker external URL from clients network

Tags: mulesoft, mule4, cloudhub

I have a mule application deployed on cloudhub. My client is trying to trigger the mule-worker URL (http://mule-worker-appname.us-e2.cloudhub.io:8081) from his network (connecting to their VPN), but it is giving Timed Out error. However, when he tries to hit with SLB URL (http://appname.us-e2.cloudhub.io) he is getting the response.

When client disconnects his VPN then worker URL is also working.

Can someone explain why the worker url is not working where as SLB url is working? I thought worker external url is a public url and can be accessed, then why there is a restriction from their network? Is there some firewalls that client must be having?

Comment: what is the full URL that your client is sending request to? Are they including port number too?

Comment: yes they are including port number also

Comment: you should explicitly mention the port number in your question. Also the application name is missing. If you don't want to share the actual name just replace it by something generic (example: myapp). As it is now it just looks like you are using an incomplete URL.

Comment: I had mentioned while writing the question looks like it got deleted when I posted the question. My bad

Answer (score 0):

When accessing the worker directly (ie using http(s)://mule-worker-myappname.region.cloudhub.io:port) you have to add explicitly the default HTTP (8081) or HTTPS (8082) ports to the request. Example: `http://mule-worker-testapp.us-e2.cloudhub.io:8081)

Also if in the [VPC firewall](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/vpc-firewall-rules-concept) those ports are blocked of access from anywhere (ie public Internet access) you may not be able to access.